# Windows service is not starting after first successfull run

Tags: c#, windows-services

I created a windows service, which will send mails to users based up on some conditions. 
I had it installed on server in automatic mode. From the logs i can see that it ran successfully for first time and ended.

And i did not see it running again in the logs after that.

I checked the service in admin tools and it says it is started.

I also restarted service but no use, it did not start again.

Below is the code i used to start the service.

```
public partial class ScheduledService : ServiceBase
{
    Timer timer;
    private DateTime lastRun = DateTime.Now;
    private DateTime DailyRunTime = Convert.ToDateTime(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DailyRunTime"]);
    public ScheduledService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //GetDocRetentionList DocList = new GetDocRetentionList();
        //DocList.GetDataSet();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        TraceService("start service");
        //timer = new Timer(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        timer = new Timer(10 * 60 * 1000);
        timer.Start();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        double TimerInterval = Convert.ToDouble(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Timer"]);
        timer.Interval = TimerInterval;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        TraceService("stopping service");
    }

    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TraceService("Service started at " + DateTime.Now);
        if (lastRun.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now > DailyRunTime)
            {
                GetDocRetentionList DocList = new GetDocRetentionList();
                DocList.GetDataSet();
                timer.Stop();
                lastRun = DateTime.Now.Date;
                //timer.Start();
            }
        }

    }
```

Any help i can get in this regard will be really helpful. Plz let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. your service is set to execute once, then it shuts the timer off in the `OnElapsedTime` method but never turns itself back on.

The first thing `OnElapsedTime` should do is turn off the timer.  The last thing it should do is turn it back on.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. this should resolve my issue i am testing it now